# How to run a script after snap install?

Tags: snap

I'm trying to package a prebuilt application whose source looks something like this.

```
   lib/
   usr/
   mybinary
   abc.sh
```

With the basic metadata this package is installed and is available via commandline 'mybinary'.
However we have a script 'abc.sh' that adds a desktop icon. How can I run this is script post installation so that a desktop icon is added by generating 'app.desktop' file. This source is pulled from cloud and I cannot add a 'app.desktop' file to the source itself.

Here's the snapcraft.yaml

```
name: mybinary
version: abcd
summary: abcd
description: abcd
grade: stable
parts:
  mybinary:
    plugin: dump
    source: *url here* 
apps:
  mybinary:
    command: mybinary
```

Answer (score 0):

In the specific case of a desktop file (and icon), you can place them in the `snap/gui` directory in your project tree, and you won't need to run the post-install script. If it's another type of file, you can add another part (files from all parts are added to the same location in the stage step).